# Completely locked out of MySQL via WAMP!

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I've somehow managed to completely lock myself out of MySQL on WAMP. It seems all privileges are denied for all users. The only way I can get into MySQL is via the command prompt but without entering a user. From there, I quite literally cannot do anything... all privileges are denied. I've tried updating the root password to no avail.

I've also tried completely uninstalling WAMP as well as MySQL. After uninstalling MySQL, I deleted the data directories inside them to get rid of all the info there. After re-installing WAMP, the problem persists.

Attempts to access PHPMyAdmin results in:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try in an elevated command prompt:

1:
`net stop mysql`

2:
`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

3:
`mysql -u root`

Output will look like this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1 to server version: 5.5.13

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

4: Here you will reset your root password:

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE USER SET password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

5:
`mysqladmin shutdown`

6: Now you can start MySQL and test it:

```
net start mysql
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Where do I type these commands in? (I'm on windows)

Comment: are you sure these commands are for windows? Both the commands you listed in #1 and #2 give me "service name is invalid" and "not recognized as an internal or external command", respectively.

Comment: @Tory- Yes, this is for Windows. You can find out more info about running MySQL as a service here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-service.html